# Segmentation fault on fgets

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

When I run the following code, it prints '>', waits for the input, and then segfaults. Does anybody know why?

```
   int main(int argc, char **argv){
        char input[MAX_INPUT_LINE];

        while(1==1){
                if (isatty(0)){
                        printf(">");
                        }
                fgets(input, MAX_INPUT_LINE, stdin);
                int len1=sizeof(input);
                for (int i=0; i<len1; i++){
                        printf("%s", input[i]);
                }
}
```

Comment: Post complete code.

Comment: From the code you post, cannot reproduce. Though you have not checked the return value from `fgets`.

Comment: just updated it

Comment: a) `sizeof input` is unrelated to what was *actually* entered. b) simple typo `%s` -> `%c`.

Comment: thank you very much! i couldnt tell the difference

Comment: More fully explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

```
 int len1=sizeof(input);        
 for (int i=0; i<len1; i++){
      printf("%s", input[i]);   // <-- %s would expect char * not char
 }
```

Use `%c` to print a character not `%s`.  `%s` would expect a nul terminated `char *` and you pass `char`, this causes undefined behaviour.

`sizeof` would return size of the array not length of string . So use `strlen` to get length of string.